# Is there any way that is more concise than mine, to send a mail with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer but I think it's taking too many lines and feel I can make it more concise. Some of the parameters below are redundant because everything is gonna be sent from the same email address.

I'm actually asking if I can put the parameters that are always the same somewhere else (From, FromName, Username, Password, Host,Post,SMTPSecure, SMTPAuth)

How can I do it? Thanks in advance. Regards

My code is:

```
include("classes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
include("classes/phpmailer/class.smtp.php"); // note, this is optional 

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = 'This is the body';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port

$mail->Username   = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "mypassword";            // GMAIL password

$mail->From       = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Admin";
$mail->Subject    = "Welcome";
$mail->AltBody    = 'This is the body'; //Text Body
$mail->WordWrap   = 100; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddReplyTo("replyto@yourdomain.com","Admin");
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->AddAddress($email,$firstname." ".$surname);

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
// nothing is displayed
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to break the code apart into re-usable pieces, or asking if you can cut down on the line count?

Comment: Hi. I'm actually asking if I can put the parameters that are always the same somewhere else (From, FromName, Username, Password, Host,Post,SMTPSecure, SMTPAuth). Regards

Comment: if you want less options use mail();

Comment: @Dagon mail() is full of header-injection security problems.

Comment: swiftmailer ( http://swiftmailer.org ) is great, though, and very concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function New_Mail($body, $subject, $altBody, $wordwrap)
{
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port

    $mail->Username   = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";            // GMAIL password

    $mail->From       = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "Admin";
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody    = $altBody; //Text Body
    $mail->WordWrap   = $wordwrap; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddReplyTo("replyto@yourdomain.com","Admin");
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    return $mail;
}

$mail = New_Mail("this is the body", "Welcome", "Another body", 100);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
// nothing is displayed
}
```

Now you reuse that function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks for that. Regards

Comment: Should I put that in the PHPMailer Class file? Thanks

Comment: No... don't modify the original libraries.  Just put that in your own code.

Comment: You can combine `SMTPSecure`, `Host` and `Port` into just the `Host` property, like this: `$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';`.

Comment: Also setting `From`, `Fromname` and `Sender` can be condensed into: `$mail->setFrom('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Admin');`

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper class for the phpmailer class which initializes all the default values and only set the values that changes.

I use a following class in my Kohana developed site:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Author Mārtiņš Briedis
 * @Date: 2011-12-11
 */

class Mail{
    /**
     * Get an instance of PHPMailer
     * @static
     * @return PHPMailer
     */
    public static function factory(){
        $inst = new PHPMailer(true);

        // Initialize defaults
        $conf = array(..); // Array with configuration data
        $inst->SetFrom($conf['from_mail'], $conf['from_name']);
        $inst->AddReplyTo($conf['from_mail'], $conf['from_name']);
        $inst->Subject = $conf['subject'];

        // If development environment, use GMAIL smtp server
        $inst->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $inst->Host = "smtp@gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        $inst->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
        $inst->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
        $inst->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $inst->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $inst->Username = $conf['mail']; // GMAIL username
        $inst->Password = $conf['password']; // GMAIL password

        return $inst;
    }

    /**
     * To get an instance, one should use factory method, not constructor
     */
    public function __construct(){
        throw new Exception('To get an instance, use static factory() method!');
    }
}
```

And then just use:

```
$mail = Mail::factory();
$mail->AddAddress($user->mail, $user->full_name);
$mail->Subject = "New password";
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I presume I would have to install that Kohanna framework? I edited my OP, saying: `I'm actually asking if I can put the parameters that are always the same (From, FromName, Username, Password, Host,Post,SMTPSecure, SMTPAuth)`. Is this going to help me doing that? Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited the piece of code. No, you do not need a specific framework. You can create a similiar class like mine and just use it.

You should read about DRY (dont repeat yourself) principle (just google it).

Comment: Oh ok, so I guess I would need to put it something like that:    `$conf = array(From => 'myemail@gmail.com', FromName => 'Admin')` etc.. Please let me know if i'm wrong. Thanks a lot

Comment: No, just create a class, like he did, putting all your unchanged variables (name, pword, etc) then return that instance by calling the method from your main page